# Using projected coordinate system and transformation gives ERROR 000151?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, coordinate-system, error-000151

I'm a beginner with GIS and I'm currently working on ArcGIS 10.3.
I have two distinct shapefiles: one within the projected coordinate system "NTF_Paris_Lambert_Sud_France" and the second one within "RGF_1993_Lambert_93".

When I opened the second shapefile I did the transformation "RGF_1993_To_NTF_NTv2 + NTF_Paris_To_NTF" which allowed me to correctly superimpose both of my shapefiles. Now I want to use the "Project" tool in order to change the projected coordinate system of the second shapefile on a permanent basis (in order to proceed to analysis with tools...). That's where I have a problem: the output shapefile is displaced by around 300 meters up to the North and a little bit to the West too.

Could someone help me with the method?

[image]

This is a screenshot of the "project" tool parameters. I did not filled the "geographic transformation" line because none of the proposed transformations is working and I always receive the message with Error 000151 (saying that the geotransformations are not valid).

Comment: The two CRSs use a different spheroid, so I'm betting a geographic transformation is required.

Comment: Ok, it works ! thank you, it wasn't working because I forgot to remove the automatic "new geographic transformation" suggested choice !

Comment: @Jyler I think you should expand your comment by a sentence or so into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a [comment by @Jyler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188163/projected-coordinate-system-and-transformation#comment283684_188163):

> The two CRSs use a different spheroid, so I'm betting a geographic
>   transformation is required.

and [verified by the asker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188163/projected-coordinate-system-and-transformation#comment283696_188163):

> it wasn't working because [they] forgot to remove the automatic "new
>   geographic transformation" suggested choice